# Solr - Adding JSON Document

Tags: solr

Error Message: "Cannot parse provided JSON: JSON Parse Error: char=@,position=1 AFTER='[@' BEFORE='books.json]'"

Command I tried to run: "curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr//update?commit=true' --data-binary @example/exampledocs/books.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'"

What does the error mean?
The json file books.json exist in the exampledocs directory, so according to https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-JSONFormattedIndexUpdates the above command should work

Comment: This is tricky to identify without seeing JSON. Could you please paste json here or try to add only one JSON record from UI.

Also please provide more details about SOLR version you are trying.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with how curl parses the @ .. could your shell be attempting to handle it? Are you on Windows? (in that case, using '' around parameters might not do what you expect them to do).